# Removing duplicates from an ArrayList?

Tags: java

Good afternoon everyone, I am currently studying for my Java Final and I have a review exercise that asks the reader to create a program that asks the user to input 10 integers and then to use a method to remove duplicates and display the distinct list. The method is provided for you as well. 
I've gotten the majority of the code written, in fact I thought I was done until I realized that the for loop is removing more than just duplicates.. 
Here is my code:

```
public class lab25 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i;

    //Create array list
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers!");

    //Populate
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
         numbers.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println("Your numbers are: " + numbers.toString());
    removeDuplicate(numbers);
    System.out.println("The distinct numbers are: " +numbers.toString());  
    input.close();
}
public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.contains(list.get(i))) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Just curious what I have done wrong here? I think my issue might lie in my for loop.. Thanks to all who answer.

Comment: I think it would be better to create a new list with the distinct values instead of manipulating the list while running over it with a for-loop. And to check if a value is a duplicate you should use a inner loop that runs over the previous values and compares the actual value to them.

Comment: Your problem is pretty obvious and your time would have been better spent trying to squash this bug yourself instead of posting a question here. Learn to use a debugger, it is a vey powerful and helpful tool and absolutely necessary to master if you are serious about learning java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be this one. I startet at the end of the list that I don't delete indexes the loop has to visit in the future.

```
public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int i = list.size() - 1;

    while (i > -1) {
        // check for duplicate
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (list.get(i) == list.get(j)) {
                // is duplicate: remove
                list.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, we haven't touched on sets as of yet and I was having a difficult time visualizing what I was doing incorrectly. This definitely helped. Thanks again.

Comment: This is very inefficient solution!

Comment: I think first is to learn how to do something. Space and time efficiency is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

`list.contains(list.get(i))` always returns `true`, since the `i`'th element of the `List` is contained in the `List`.

Therefore `removeDuplicate` is trying to remove all the elements (but you only remove half of them, since after removing the `i`'th element you skip the new `i`'th element).

There are many ways to remove duplicates. The most efficient involve using a `HashSet`. If you want to find duplicates using only `List` methods, you can check if `list.lastIndexOf(list.get(i)) > i`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `list.contains(list.get(i))` is always true, since you're asking if the list contains some element from the list. You need to check if `list.get(i)` is contained in the first `i-1` items in the list, which I recommend doing with a loop.

Be aware that a loop with `list.remove` will run slowly, since removing item i from an `ArrayList` is done by replacing item i with i+1, then replacing item i+1 with i+2 and so on. This means it takes around `length^2` time to make a loop that calls remove in every iteration. The function `list.contains` has the same problem, as it has to go through the entire list. This may not matter if you have 10 items, but if you had a list with a million items, it would take a long time to run.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest ways is to use `Stream.distinct()`:

```
public static List<Integer> removeDuplicate(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In case you are free to choose collection, you should use `LinkedHashSet` instead. It holds ordered unique numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the list.get(i) which of course is present in the list, and you will delete all of the values in the end.
You could remove them by using a set:

```
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
hs.addAll(numbers);
numbers.clear();
numbers.addAll(hs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the current order and do not want to use set.

```
List<String> notduplicatedList =
    new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(String));
```